# What am I doing wrong with this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, gsap

I'm still in the learning stage of ajax and scripting. I recently stumbled upon this website http://www.maisonbertine.com/ found it very interesting using this script for loading the menu and contents.

I tried to learn and mimic the code on my testing website http://www.ztest.ca but I couldn't get it to work. If it works, it should load the Left Menu and Right Main H1 from www.ztest.ca/en/en.html

The after clicking on the language link, it does not change the url to www.ztest.ca/en/ so I guess the pushState method didn't execute. Also Firefox console is showing POST ztest.ca/en/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 209ms].

Below are the current code:

Language selection container:

```
<div id="container"><aside id="leftsidebar" class="is-white is-left"></aside>
    <div class="lang" id="lang">
        <div class="lang_logo"></div>
        <div class="lang_selection" id="lang_selection">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/en/">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="/fr/">Français</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script used to perform the TweenMax animation:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>        
<script src="/js/libs/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        if($(document).width()<736){
            return false;
        }
        var tween1 = new TimelineMax();
        tween1.add([
            TweenMax.to("#lang", 1.3, {delay: 1, z: 0, left: 160, autoAlpha: 1, ease: Expo.easeOut,force3D:true}),
        ]);
        tween1.add([
            TweenMax.to("#lang_selection", 0.5, {z: 0, left: 160, ease: Expo.easeOut, force3D:true})
        ]);
        $lang = $('#lang_selection');
        $lang.on('click', 'a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $a = $(this);
            var href= $a.attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url:href,
                type:'post',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $html = $(response.page.html);
                    $wrapright = $($html[0]);
                    var nav = response.mainnav;
                    $container = $('#container');
                    $container.prepend($wrapright);
                    $('#leftsidebar').html(nav);
                    if(Modernizr.history){
                        window.history.pushState({href:'/'},'','/');
                        window.history.pushState({href:href},'',href);
                        document.title = response.page.seotitel;
                    }
                    tween1.add([
                        TweenMax.to("#lang_selection", 0.8, {z: 0, left: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut,force3D:true})
                    ]);
                    tween1.add([
                        TweenMax.to("#lang", 0.8, {z: 0, left: -200, ease: Expo.easeOut,force3D:true})
                    ]);
                    tween1.add([
                        TweenMax.to("#leftsidebar", 1.5, {z: 0, left: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut,force3D:true})
                    ]);
                    tween1.add([
                        TweenMax.to("#overlay", 0.9, {z: 0, autoAlpha: 1,force3D:true})
                    ]);
                    tween1.add([
                        TweenMax.to("#main h1", 2, {z: 0, top: '25%', autoAlpha: 1, ease: Expo.easeOut,force3D:true}),
                    ]);
                }
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

I think the problem is occurring here:

```
    $lang = $('#lang_selection');
    $lang.on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $a = $(this);
        var href= $a.attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url:href,
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(response){
                $html = $(response.page.html);
                $wrapright = $($html[0]);
                var nav = response.mainnav;
                $container = $('#container');
                $container.prepend($wrapright);
                $('#leftsidebar').html(nav);
                if(Modernizr.history){
                    window.history.pushState({href:'/'},'','/');
                    window.history.pushState({href:href},'',href);
                    document.title = response.page.seotitel;
                }
```

Please help me find the mistake I made here. Thank you!

Comment: you're calling `pushState` 2 times, what exactly is your intent :) ?

Comment: this is the part I'm confused with, I'm just trying to test the same code from www.maisonbertine.com but I just couldn't get it to work on mine. I think the problem exists within:
$lang = $('#lang_selection');
$lang.on('click', 'a', function(e){...} 
but I just couldn't find what's causing the problem.

Comment: when you say `history.pushState(stateObj, stateName, url)`, it will change the `url` in address bar without actually firing a request for that resource. When you click back in browser, a 'popstate' event will be fired whose `state` property contains the `stateObj` that you passed. I suggest you read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Example)

Comment: Do you see any error in Dev Tools -> Console ?

Comment: Hi Arkantos, thank you for clarifying the usage, so that's the case when I click the language link it should at least change to ztest.com/en/, but it is not working. In Firefox console, I do see that it showed POST http://ztest.ca/en/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 209ms]. So I guess the problem is occurring between "$lang = $('#lang_selection');"  and  "if(Modernizr.history){" so there is no problem (possibly) with the pushState method, because it didn't get executed yet.

Comment: So there's an Ajax call going to `ztest.ca/en` but you said your page is at `ztest.ca/en/en.html`, so i suggest you update the `href` of anchor tags accordingly :-)

Comment: I do have the .htaccess setup for en.html or index.html so ztest.ca/en should open en.html automatically. this code works for the original maisonbertine website but it doesn't work on mine :(.

Comment: Hmm.. Try putting a debug point in success function in FF Debugger..

Comment: What is the response you get in that Ajax call ? Did you check the preview of your response ? Also do you see any script errors after Ajax call ?

Comment: I used the debugger to break at success: function(response), both sites worked and came back with the same result, but when I tried to break just after the success function at $html = $(response.page.html); my site did not do anything, but the original site continued. I think this might be where the problem lies?

Comment: Original site is returning JSON response, what is your site returning ? Click on your Ajax call in `Network -> Response` tab and see if the structure is same

Comment: The original site is definitely returning JSON response, my site just loaded the entire /en/ page. Where do I click on my Ajax call? I see Network -> response but not sure what to do next.

Comment: you can add a screen shot of your Ajax call response :)

Comment: As the original site returns JSON response, they just access properties of that JSON object but in your case I think you're getting `html`, so instead of looking for property just replace the html in your container something like `$('#container').html(response);. Remove all other lines dealing with `response`

Comment: Hi Arkantos, sorry I was away for a couple days. After trying all this its still not working, i'm giving up with the animated loading just doing a straight forward linking. Thank you so much for helping me out :D